# Decoding Cyrillic string in R

Tags: r, decode, encode, iconv

I would like to decode this string in R: `РѕР±РµР·РїРµС‡РµРЅ`. The desired output should be: `обезпечен`

This [site](https://2cyr.com/decode/) suggest that the source encoding is `UTF-8` and it should be trans-coded to `Windows-1251`. So I tried with no success this:

```
> word <- "РѕР±РµР·РїРµС‡РµРЅ"
> iconv(word, from = "UTF-8",to = "Windows-1251")
[1] "Ð¾Ð±ÐµÐ·Ð¿ÐµÑ‡ÐµÐ½"
```

Comment: Not sure why it happens like so in R, but in python we have `>>> "РѕР±РµР·РїРµС‡РµРЅ".encode("cp1251").decode("utf-8")
'обезпечен'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These steps seem to do the trick

```
word <- "РѕР±РµР·РїРµС‡РµРЅ"

xx <- iconv(word, from="UTF-8", to="cp1251")
Encoding(xx) <- "UTF-8"
xx
# [1] "обезпечен"

target <- "обезпечен"
xx == target
# [1] TRUE
```

So it seems what happened was at one point the bytes that make up the UTF-8 `target` value were misinterpreted as being cp1251 encoded and somewhere a process ran to convert the bytes to UTF-8 based on the cp1251->UTF-8 mapping rules. However, when you run this on data that insn't really cp1251 encoded you get weird values.

```
iconv(target, from="cp1251", to="UTF-8")
# "РѕР±РµР·РїРµС‡РµРЅ"
```

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick! This solution really works, but I still don't understand the intuition behind it.

Comment: @Svilen It seems at some pint the bytes of `target` were misinterpreted `target` as being cp1251 encoded rather than utf-8 encoded. Something then triggered a reencoding to convert to utf-8, which gets you to the incorrect encoded version: `iconv(target, from="cp1251", to="UTF-8")`. So at some point an incorrect transformation occurred. The solution looks odd because it's fixing a weird mistake rather than something that's expected to happen.